# Do calculation on text formatted as single number format in C#

Tags: c#

I understand how to format some number text into a number format using string.format function like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", "5000.52");

// Outputs: 5,000.52
```

but the real issue for me is when using this formatted text again in some calculation like this:

```
Single y = Single.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * 123;
```

C# compiler complains and says:

`System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'`

So, I need to know what is the professional way to overcome this issue as I really concerned about my application performance.

Comment: replace `"5000.52"` with `5000.52f`

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. That code does not throw that exception. This also has very little to do with performance. Is your question _"How to parse a decimal/float/double from a string"_?

Comment: The code that causes the error is missing.

Comment: If you're concerned about application performance, don't convert it to a string except where you need to display it. I'm assuming you had a number, converted it to a string and formatted it, and now want to reuse it as a number. You should only convert it to a string to display it.

Comment: I think it is a self explaining code and if you paste into C# editor and try to compile it. it would be the same exception mentioned above, However I will revise my question to have it complaint with website rules.

Comment: Because it's not a number, it's a string

Comment: "when using this formatted text again in some calculation" is neither self explanatory nor compiling very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the real issue for me is when using this formatted text again in
>   some calculation, C# compiler complains and says:

The professional way to overcome this, is store the number as a number, and format it only for display purposes. Don't be converting numbers to text to number unless you really have no other choice (which i doubt).

```
var myAwesomeNumber = 5000.52f;

textbox1.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", myAwesomeNumber);

// do stuff with my awesome number again

myAwesomeNumber += 1;
```

if you really need to parse a formatted integer from text, then you need look into the various overloads for parse

[Single.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzs0sca(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style
>   and culture-specific format to its single-precision floating-point
>   number equivalent.

Take a look at the examples

Comment: Why `String.Format("{0:n}", "5000.52");`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman was just copied form his example, however thanks point taken :)

Comment: Do you mean there is no some way do this conversion, as I do not like two much variables which make to much noise and headache?

Comment: @AhmedNazmy updated my answer, but `as I do not like two much variables` this is really a bad excuse though

Comment: Ahmed.  Always (repeat, always) store numbers as numbers and format for display.  Many years ago I inherited a program (in VB6) that calculated salaries for employees.  Numbers were stored as a property of labels.  Subtle errors were introduced when converting to a numeric, doing a calculation and the converting back to a string for display.  Results were inconsistent.  Raises (as a percentage) were calculated incorrectly.  We re-wrote the program using the same idea TheGeneral stated.  Your code would not pass a code review because of what is called 'etc' (evil type coercion).